# Actionview - Render outputs plain array of objects instead of HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I have an Rails' actionview partial which iterates through objects in hierarchy - branch objects (simulating array) contains leafs or branch objects, etc. For each branch objects, I have partial with the following code:

```rb
branch.each do |child|
  render partial: child.class.to_s.underscore, object: child, layout: child.layout
end
```

The output is literately:

```
[#<LeafObject:0x007fbf6806f480 @id="obj1">, #<LeafObject:0x007fbf700c80c8 @id="obj2">]
```

Considering the partials for those leafs objects contains `<%= leaf_object.id %><br />`, I would expect the following output:

```
obj1<br />obj2<br />
```

Here's where it's getting weird. If I call `render` on the objects within the branch array directly, it works but only when I do it individually. Seems like the buffer for the first object is overwritten by the second one.

```rb
render partial: branch[0].class.to_s.underscore, object: branch[0], layout: branch[0].layout
render partial: branch[1].class.to_s.underscore, object: branch[1], layout: branch[1].layout
```

Produces...

```
obj2<br />
```

Yes, I know: WTF!?! It's like if render would act differently within an Enumerator.

Also, keep in mind I'm not using collections because the layout change for each objects (i.e. branch[0].layout). Using collections works but not per object layout.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is calling render multiple times a bad thing? Any though would be appreciated.

Versions: Ruby: 1.9.3, Rails: 3.2.10

Answer (score 0):

Just checking, but did you leave some ERB tags out?

```
<% branch.each do |child| %>
  <%= render partial: child.class.to_s.underscore, object: child, layout: child.layout %>
<% end %>
```

Because your incorrect output:

```
[#<LeafObject:0x007fbf6806f480 @id="obj1">, #<LeafObject:0x007fbf700c80c8 @id="obj2">]
```

suggests that you are actually doing something like:

```
<%= branch %>
```

Comment: The branch.each loop is within a helper but I'll double check for something like <%= branch %>